# Flutter hide bottom navigation bar

Tags: flutter, navigation

i'm using the package PersistentBottomNavBar is there a way to hide the bottom navigation bar on certain pages ?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `withNavBar:false` it is true by defult
[navigator-functions](https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar#navigator-functions)

When you push to newscreen instead of using  `Navigator.push()` use following navigator `pushNewScreen()`and if you don't want bottomnavbar in the pushed screen set as withNavBar:false

```
pushNewScreen(
        context,
        screen: MainScreen(),
        withNavBar: false, 
        pageTransitionAnimation: PageTransitionAnimation.cupertino,
    );
```

Comment: so i put pushNewScreen inside the class of the page that i don't want it to have the navigation bar ?

Comment: when you push to newscreen instead of using ` Navigator.push()` use above navigator(pushNewScreen), and if you don't want bottombar in the pushed screen set as `withNavBar:false`@WassefHassine

Comment: This doesn't work correctly! 
When you return to previous page the navigation bar disappeared. Even you put withNavBar: true on return.

Answer (score 0):

I think u need either navigate to another page or hide the navigation bar and show again when it needs.

Comment: yeah, but how exactly , couldn't find a way to do that

Comment: I guess when u tap on buttons u will be informed about changing your current position.  So use if statement. 

you need to pass null to Scaffold for bottomNavigationBar parameter to hide the bar